# Is a database required for a "quiz" type of game?

Tags: javascript, html, css, database

I don't know much about databases, I've been asking a few questions about them lately to get a better understanding but I'm still a bit confused about what does and doesn't need one.

I'm making a simple application using HTML/CSS/JavaScript, it has a few quizzes and "tutorials" targeted towards children. I don't want the next tutorial/quiz to be unlocked until the previous one is completed.

So for that would I need a database so that it "saves" when one is completed? I don't need to save scores or anything like that, they just get to move on once they get a passing score.

Comment: yes, the answers has the be on the server, otherwise everyone can see answers!

Comment: I have a friend who made something like this for a class he was in. He used pure JS. It depends on whether you want people to be able to cheat by going into their console and poking about.

Comment: If you are not concerned with cheating, it is easy enough to record the client's progress using a cookie.  They can go and edit the cookie to hop to the end, but it may suffice for your purposes.

Comment: Given this is targeted toward children, I wouldn't be too concerned with a database for this.

Comment: @jsve I'm actually going to be making it into an Android application using Cordova, would that make it more difficult for someone to cheat?

Comment: @DrewKennedy so it is all possible to do with JavaScript? What would be the advantages of having a database? Would it be for security reasons like Mitch mentioned?

Comment: Sure. A solid possibility for you may be local storage. The storage size limit is far larger than cookies, is more secure than cookies, and it super easy to work with (as stated in Brad's answer).

Comment: Storing in database doesn't have a big security benefit. You can check answers and save (whichever method) status of a user server-side and create it as a secured token on the client.

Comment: I don't think you can access a browser console from Cordova (you'd have to check on that), but if you can't, yes, it would make it harder to cheat (especially for children which your app will be targeted towards).

Comment: @jsve perfect that would be great, but yeah it's targeted towards children in Kindergarten so I would be amazed and slightly terrified if they figured out how to cheat!

Comment: @roguerat, if I was the owner of a company (which I'm not) I'd want to hire that kindergartener on the spot. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any other requirements such as saving to a profile or needing to persist between sessions (e.g. changing of device)?

Browsers have [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) APIs now which allow you to save a lot of the data (and keep it for a set duration of time). There are also good'ol'fashioned cookies which allow you save pieces of information as well.

Keep in mind that both of the above mandate the user use the same browser and allow these mechanisms. Obviously using "private"/"incognito" browsing would also affect saving status.

It's up to what you feel the requirements are.

**EDIT** Just saw your mention of a mobile app. If you're planning on allowing the experience to transcend devices, you'll need a database. otherwise, you'll be relying heavily on if they use cross-device sync (like Chrome and Firefox do with bookmarks, passwords, etc.)

Comment: I plan on making it into an app using Cordova. I want the person to open the app and see the list of lessons in order, but only have access to the latest one they haven't completed. They don't need any sign up or point system, maybe in the future I can add that once I know databases better. But since I'm using Cordova, does that make localStorage even more stable as it will always use the same browser by default? Also, if someone were to clear their phones history would that also clear all of their progress in my app?

Comment: Yes, same browser. Yes, clearing the browser means clearing his/her status/accomplishments. And I'm not sure what age bracket, but you may look into logging in with facebook/twitter/etc. 1. You won't have to worry about storing passwords, and 2. kids these days usually have an account already and makes it easier for them. Also, a local account on your site would allow you to perpetuate progress across sessions (and yes, using a database).

Comment: Ah so if they sign in through Facebook I could save all of their progress to their Facebook account without having a database of my own? I didn't know that. I've used the Facebook sign-in in the past with Rails but also had my own database. The only difference was I used Facebook instead of Devise for user creation. So, I could make it so all of the quiz information gets saved right to their Facebook account?

Comment: Not quite... Facebook sign-in doesn't alleviate you needing a database. It just makes the login process (and therefore the password remember problem) easier on a child. The login, however, gives you a specific account reference that you can then store the quiz progress to (in your own database).

Comment: @roguerat Of course you do need to keep in mind what it means to connect to Facebook / Twitter. Depending on the kind of quiz you might not want to share it with 3rd parties and/or link the results to accounts that are connected to their real/offline identities.

Comment: Absolutely. I wont be connecting this app with social media as the app itself is all about teaching young children the importance of the internet and how it all works. I see a lot of my younger cousins (5-8 years old) posting ridiculous things online they will regret when they're older. Every kid is now born with the internet, yet not many people are teaching them how it works and why they need to use it responsibly. So that's what I'm trying to do with this project.

Comment: :applause: Do you have one for my age bracket? My wall's crowded with the aforementioned posts, and I'm late 20's. ;-\

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind that people can do a "view source" on the webpage or use every browsers' developer tools to find out the answers or move on to the next tutorial or quiz, then you can [use cookies to store](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/setcookie/) the user's status. Or you can use the preferable [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

You might want to look at [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/). Using just simple JavaScript on the web browser, you can have users with logins (or just allow them to login via Facebook or other services) very easily. And then you can store and retrieve data very easily as well, like quizzes, tutorials and results. This way nobody can see the answers even if they're adept at analyzing the webpage.

Comment: Wow, cool. Didn't know about Firebase. I'm a .net web developer, so it looks like localStorage meets signalR.

Comment: @BradChristie - I'm a big fan of Firebase. It's a very well-thought out system that just works. In a way that obviates the need for a backend (well you use their backend) and does so in a fault-tolerant reliable way from the user's perspective. I actually teach very young kids to use Firebase!

Answer (score 1):

When you don't use database, before any check, you have to load all data in your static page.

So My sloution: store students situation in a cookie. On each page check cookie status and then use Jquery remove() to remove (Client-side) those parts of page that he/she can not access.

EDIT

This wont work when JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: You can use CSS `display:none;` and show it as needed. Seem better IMO.

Comment: Thank you. As a hack jquery.show() can reveal hidden element but removed elements can not be undone.

Comment: Ali, you could also remove the other elements if needed. I just pointed you can safely load the page without exposing every question for people with JS disabled.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that you are suggesting jquery.hide() instead of remove(). Besides your link to facebook not worked at your website ;)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of ideas but no clarifying on the database subject.

TL;DR is: No.

Now for the specifics. A database is nothing more than a way to store information. While traditional "SQL" databases (it is pronounced "Sequel" as in "My Sequel" for MySQL) have concepts of tables, where you define columns with items to store and saves each row with its value, much like an Excel file, some databases like Redis store key-value pairs and others lide MongoDB store JavaScript Objects.

You can store information in the source code (As Variables possibly) or in a file. A database is a way to organize that information.

With that said, in your case, you probably need a backend or an API. An API is basically a means of communication with a server through AJAX (JavaScript in the browser asks for stuff). That would be your way to retrieve information from the server as needed, so that users wouldn't see the answers before they answer.

With that out of the way, there are some options. FireBase (As noted on other answer) and AppBase are easy ways to integrate this concept with little effort. But they tie you and your information to their system, and they are mostly targeting more resource intensive apps.

Since you are using JS and seem to be enjoying your learning experience, I would suggest you consider suing NodeJS and defining the data as either a JSON file or a variable in JS. You keep working on your problem but add options and get to learn some stuff.

If you decide to integrate a database and possibly do some neat stuff, you have most of the groundwork done already.

If NodeJS picks your interest, Mean.IO and KrakenJS are, in my opinion, the best places to start, though they may both seem overkill in your specific case.

Do consider though: A database is just a small possible piece in a puzzle, and it's mostly a horrible way to name some of the software that tries to organize your information. Consider first if you need to organize information, and what and how do you need to organize, then start thinking if databases are the best way to organize it.